# Programmatically simulating Android OS killing my app

Tags: android

My application behaves a certain incorrect way after it is killed by the OS while running in the background. In trying to debug this, I've had to basically wait for the OS to do this on every go around - this is very slow, so I was wondering if there was a way of programmatically telling the OS to kill my app.

I have tried `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` and `finish()` but those don't seem to produce the same behavior as the natural way does.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's a common Android behaviour when it's low on memory. Does finish(); not work? It should kill your app

Comment: Yes, that does not work.

Comment: You can convert 2,3 jpg images in background to Bitmap without recycling..it will kill your app immediately for Memory Overflow...

Comment: You can start the email intent, and your app will be blown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go on your phone to `Settings | Developers Options` and set `'Don't keep Activities'` checkbox. I'm not sure about exact wording.

This way as soon as any your Activity is in background it immediately gets killed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting on **Don't Keep Activity** feature inside **Developer Options**.

When you leave each Activity (Because you start another one), Android will kill it (When you are running on low Memory Android behaves this way). Setting this feature on, you will be forced to manage in the proper way the state of each Activity using `onSaveInstanceState()` and checking por savedInstanceState Bundle in your `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

try the below process:

```
 go to settings->developer options->check the "don't keep activities" checkbox.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) that is a excelent Android Emulator. 
It let you set the battery level and other configurations that can finish your application and do what you want.